# Analyse .NET code with SonarQube on Linux platform

Tags: .net, linux, sonarqube, static-analysis, fxcop

I need to perform static code analysis of .NET project using SonarQube.

I have 2 machines:

1. Linux with Sonar Server
2. Windows with .net code and its tools (Fxcop, ...)

I need to perform analysis on Windows and push the results to Sonar Server on Linux machine.

Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to have the appropriate plugins installed in your SonarQube server, so C# if it's not there already.

Then you'll install SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild on the Windows machine, and run the analysis there because full/proper analysis of .NET code requires MSBuild and that's not gonna work on Linux. Don't worry, there's no problem running the analysis on a different machine than the one that hosts your SonarQube server.

Essentially, you set up a build step to eavesdrop on the MSBuild execution, then you run the analysis based on the data gathered during the build.

Full details [in the docs](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+MSBuild).

Comment: Don't know what to tell you @GaganBajaj. It works for me.

Comment: It would be nice if you could [edit] these details into the question.

Comment: I've expanded somewhat @GaganBajaj

Comment: Thanks G. Ann its quite helpful.